# Dynamically Changing Combobox to TextBox in datagrid inside Cell Editing Template in silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I'm making an application in Silverlight 4. I am facing a problem, I need to change a particular combobox into textbox programmatically when a particular column value(using combobox) of the same row is changed.I need to change this on event cellEditEnded.

Please note that I need to change celleditingtemplate combobox to textbox not celltemplate textblock.

This my Column  where I need to take the decision of its  combo box selected value.

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Instruction Type" 
    CanUserResize="False" CanUserReorder="False">
    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock  Margin="2" Text="{Binding operationType}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox   x:Name="instruction" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

This Column comboBox need to change  to textbox here:

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Destination">
    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding destination}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox  x:Name="destination"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

C# code:

```
public class Instruction
{
    public string operationType { get; set; }
    public string destination { get; set; }
}

private void myGrid_CellEditEnded(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid obj = (DataGrid)sender;
    Instruction obj1 = (Instruction)obj.SelectedItem;

    if (e.Column.Header.ToString() == "Instruction Type")
    {
        if (obj1.operationType == "ADD" || obj1.operationType == "SUB")
        {
            // Here I need Require Code ????/
        } 
    }
}
```

I m waitng for anyone Genius who help me out ..

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example http://anzensoft.smtp.ru/FlashKiller2/DataGridTrickTestPage.html

And here is the source code http://cid-a1de71e9f2ae2f82.office.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/DataGridTrick.zip

xaml code

---

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <sdk:DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                  PreparingCellForEdit="dataGrid1_PreparingCellForEdit">
        <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Instruction Type">
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock  Margin="2" Text="{Binding operationType}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox x:Name="instruction" 
                                  SelectedValue="{Binding operationType, Mode=TwoWay}">
                            <s:String>ADD</s:String>
                            <s:String>MUL</s:String>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Destination">
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding destination}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <ComboBox x:Name="destinationComboBox" 
                                      SelectedValue="{Binding destination, Mode=TwoWay}">
                                <s:String>sdas</s:String>
                                <s:String>dasdasdasd</s:String>
                            </ComboBox>
                            <TextBox x:Name="destinationTextBox" 
                                     Text="{Binding destination, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                     Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
    </sdk:DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

C# code

---

```
namespace DataGridTrick
{
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
    }

    void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = new List<Instruction>()
        {
            new Instruction(){operationType = "ADD", destination ="sdas"},
            new Instruction(){operationType = "ADD", destination = "dasdasdasd"}
         };
    }

    private void dataGrid1_PreparingCellForEdit(object sender, DataGridPreparingCellForEditEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((string)e.Column.Header == "Destination")
        {
            var tb = e.EditingElement.FindName("destinationTextBox") as TextBox;
            var cb = e.EditingElement.FindName("destinationComboBox") as ComboBox;
            var instruction = e.EditingElement.DataContext as Instruction;

            if (tb == null || cb == null || instruction == null)
            {
                throw new 
                Exception("Something wrong here.. this dosen't have to happen!!");
            }
            else
            {
                if (instruction.operationType == "MUL")
                {
                    tb.DataContext = e.EditingElement.DataContext;
                    cb.DataContext = null;

                    tb.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                    cb.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
                else
                {
                    tb.DataContext = null;
                    cb.DataContext = e.EditingElement.DataContext;

                    tb.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
                    cb.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Instruction
{
    public string operationType { get; set; }
    public string destination { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: edited answer a litte (you don't have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in data, to make this example work)

Comment: Alright thanks Mr. Ai_Boy. your code is working. You are really Genious..!!